# Can't write to ,dat files in Julia

Tags: julia

So I'm pretty much a Julia noob and decided to write the Ising model. Everything went well except I don't seem to be able to write my arrays (which contain magnetization and energies) to a .dat file.

I tried various ways of writing to .dat file but the code just throws UndefRefError on the line where I'm trying to write to the file.

`file = open("lattice_eqm.dat", "w") for i in 1:length(TIME_ARR)     write(file, string(TIME_ARR[i]), "\t", string(MAGNETIZATION_PER_SPIN_ARR[i]), "\t", string(ENERGY_PER_SPIN_ARR[i]), "\n") end close(file)`

This is how I'm trying to write to the file. Below is the entire code.

```
function Ising(J_ising, T, L, EQUI_STEPS, SIM_STEPS)
    setprecision(50)

# rand(Bool, n, n) creates a matrix with random 1 and 0
    LATTICE_SPINS = 2*rand(Bool, L, L).-1 #hence this will make a matrix with random 1 and -1
    E, M = 0, 0

# now finding the intial magnetization and the intial energy
    E = -J_ising * sum((LATTICE_SPINS[i, j] * (LATTICE_SPINS[i, mod1(j+1, L)]) + LATTICE_SPINS[i, mod1(j-1, L)] + LATTICE_SPINS[mod1(i+1, L), j] + LATTICE_SPINS[mod1(i-1, L), j]) for i in 1:L for j in 1:L)
    M = sum(LATTICE_SPINS[i, j] for i in 1:L for j in 1:L)

    E_per_spin = E/(2*(L*L))
    M_per_spin = M/(L*L)
    println("The initial energy per spin is $E_per_spin and the inital magnetization per spin is $M_per_spin")

# define arrays that will contain final values
    ENERGY_PER_SPIN_ARR = Array{BigFloat}(undef, 1)
    MAGNETIZATION_PER_SPIN_ARR = Array{BigFloat}(undef, 1)
    TIME_ARR = Array{Int32}(undef, 1)
    

# now to reach eqm
    for t in 1:EQUI_STEPS

        i, j = rand(1:L), rand(1:L)

        delE = J_ising * (((LATTICE_SPINS[i, j] * (LATTICE_SPINS[i, mod1(j+1, L)]) + LATTICE_SPINS[i, mod1(j-1, L)] + LATTICE_SPINS[mod1(i+1, L), j] + LATTICE_SPINS[mod1(i-1, L), j])) - (((-LATTICE_SPINS[i, j] * (LATTICE_SPINS[i, mod1(j+1, L)]) + LATTICE_SPINS[i, mod1(j-1, L)] + LATTICE_SPINS[mod1(i+1, L), j] + LATTICE_SPINS[mod1(i-1, L), j]))))

        if delE < 0
            E += delE
            M += 2*LATTICE_SPINS[i, j]
        
        else
            prob = exp(-delE/T)
            random = rand()
            
            if random < prob
                LATTICE_SPINS[i, j] = -LATTICE_SPINS[i, j]
                E += delE
                M += 2*LATTICE_SPINS[i, j]
            end
        end
        push!(TIME_ARR, t)
        push!(MAGNETIZATION_PER_SPIN_ARR, M/(L*L))
        push!(ENERGY_PER_SPIN_ARR, E/(L*L))
    end

    # writing to dat file
    file = open("lattice_eqm.dat", "w")
    for i in 1:length(TIME_ARR)    
        write(file, string(TIME_ARR[i]), "\t", string(MAGNETIZATION_PER_SPIN_ARR[i]), "\t", string(ENERGY_PER_SPIN_ARR[i]), "\n")
    end
    close(file)
end
Ising(big(0.5), big(0.2), 50, 100000, 500000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a cursory glance makes me think that the first element of your arrays are all undef, and therefore the first iteration of your final loop runs into an error.

btw, if you know how long the arrays are going to be (This is EQUI_STEPS i believe) its much more efficient to initialize the whole array, rather than pushing a value in at each iteration.